# Spring Flux from paginated calls using Link response header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Fairly new to reactive programming and the Spring webclient so I'm trying to get my head around it, essentially I have a paged list of results to consume from a REST service which responds with a Link response header with a relative URI to the next page of results if one exists. I'd like to collect all pages into a Flux. By default the generated ApiClient has something like this

```
public <T> Flux<T> invokeFluxAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams,
        List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType)
        throws RestClientException {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body,
            headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.retrieve().bodyToFlux(returnType);
}
```

So do I need to make some sort of recursive call for each page of results combining each page Mono into a flux? Eg. along the lines of

```
public <T> Flux<T> invokeFluxAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams,
        List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType)
        throws RestClientException {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body,
            headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.exchange()
            .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                List<String> links = response.headers().header("Link");
                if (!links.isEmpty()) {
                    String nextPageUri = links.get(0);
                    // Get next page using the URI
                }
            })
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(returnType));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this working by treating a `ClientResponse` as a results page eg.

```
public <T> Flux<T> invokeFluxAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams,
        List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType)
        throws RestClientException {
    return fetchResultsPage(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body, headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames).expand(response -> {
        List<String> links = response.headers().header("Link");
        if (links.isEmpty()) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }

        Matcher m = "(?<=\\<)([^\\]]+)(?=\\>)".matcher(links.get(0));

        if (!m.find())) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }

        String nextPageUri = m.group(1);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> qParams = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(nextPageUri).build().getQueryParams();

        queryParams.putAll(qParams);
        queryParams.replace("limit", qParams.get("limit"));

        return fetchResultsPage(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body, headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    }).flatMap(response -> response.bodyToFlux(returnType);
}

private Mono<ClientResponse> fetchResultsPage(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams,
        List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames) {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body,
            headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.exchange();
}
```